# WPF pass ActualWidth and ActualHeight of child control to value converter

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Using WPF, I wish to create an image for each data set in a collection and display the images stacked vertically. All the images must have the same height (and width). The images stacked together must make up the height of the containing element. The images must not be stretched in any way.

A non-working pretend example of the kind of thing I'm after is as follows.

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1" DataContext="{Binding DataSetCollection}">
    <UniformGrid.Children>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataSetToImageConverter}">
            <Binding />
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UniformGridRow}}" />
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UniformGridRow}}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </UniformGrid.Children>
</UniformGrid>
```

This doesn't work for a number of reasons but hopefully communicates the intent. Key requirements are:

- All children must be the same height
- No stretching is allowed
- Each image is created dynamically based on the area available to it
- Images are redrawn when the size of the containing element changes
- The value converter used to return the images correctly receives the width and height of the containing row

It doesn't have to use UniformGrid, it can be anything, however it should use databinding and a converter for each child.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick, binding to the size of the containing ContentPresenter.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataSetCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WriteableBitmapDataTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Using this data template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WriteableBitmapDataTemplate">
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RangeToWritableBitmapConverter}">
                <Binding />
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}" />
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</DataTemplate>
```